# What can be used in place of dynamic id for form to use in jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have an aspx content page and this inherit by master page.

In master page my main content place holder comes under a `<form>`,

```
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">

    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
```

Below is code for my content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="header" style="color: Black;">
            LOGIN USER
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="UserName: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div align="center" class="alertmsg">
</div>
```

While I going to use jQuery validation plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ctl01').validate({
            rules: {
                    <%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                     <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>: {                        
                        required: true,
                        email:true
                    }
                },
            messages: {
                    <%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>:{  
                        required: "* Required Field *",  
                        minlength: "* Please enter atleast 2 characters *"  
                    },
                    <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>:{  
                        required: "* Required Field *",  
                        email: "* Please enter valid email address *"  
                    }       
                }

        });
});

</script>
```

The dynamic id of `txtUserName` can be exposed by `<%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>`, but why do I need to give the id of the form to `$('#ctl01').validate`?
Can I use any other id in place of `#ctl01`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : Note the different between `$('<%=Form.UniqueID %>').validate({` and `$('<%=Form.UniqueID %>').validate({`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=Form.UniqueID %>').validate({
            rules: {
                    <%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                     <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>: {                        
                        required: true,
                        email:true
                    }
                },
            messages: {
                    <%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>:{  
                        required: "* Required Field *",  
                        minlength: "* Please enter atleast 2 characters *"  
                    },
                    <%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>:{  
                        required: "* Required Field *",  
                        email: "* Please enter valid email address *"  
                    }       
                }

        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: $('<%=Form.UniqueID %>') is not working, what dieerence u ask for?

Comment: Sorry I missed the `#` before `<%=Form.UniqueID %>`. Updated the answer, please re-check.

Answer (score 0):

The `.validate()` requires it to be from because you do validation to check for proper values before they are sent to the server i.e. when user submits the form  and only forms can be submitted and it is only through them that you can prevent wrong values from begin submitted..

TO be more clear:

You can refer http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate for clear description.

and If `Control.UniqueID`  doesn't works You can use `Control.ClientID`...

Comment: Use the `ID` of the Form at Design time. if it's `from1` then write `form1.ClientId`. If your form tag is in Master Page and Jquery is in child Page then simply use "`$('#aspnetForm').validate({...`".